# Como puedo hacer para que el valor del boton no sea menor a cero JqueryUI - Spinner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tengo esta funcion en jqueryUI spinner

```
$(function() {
                                        $("#numero_de_pacu1").spinner();
                                        $('button').button();

                                        $('#stepUp-2').click(function () {
                                        $("#numero_de_pacu1").spinner("stepUp");
                                        });

                                        $('#stepDown-2').click(function () {
                                        $("#numero_de_pacu1").spinner("stepDown");
                                        });  
                                    });
```

lo llamo aqui en html

-

```
<input type="number" name="numero_de_pacu1" id="numero_de_pacu1" value="0"/>
```

+

La siguiente imagen refleja como aparecen los valores
[image: Como haria para que los valores no sean menor a cero]

Answer (score 0):

Coloca los atributos max y min en el input

```
<input type="text" name="numero_de_pacu1" id="numero_de_pacu1" value="0" min="0" max="10" size="10" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #97CCF3; color: #099EFB; font-weight: bold;border-radius: 15px;" onmousemove="cambiar_inputs()"/>
```